# How to update data to xml file

Tags: esp8266

I have search lots, and finally I was able to get my project moving!
I have learned to create an xml file and get data from it using XMLRequest vía "get". 
I'm using a Nodemcu 12e v.1 I believe, have the WiFi and server running. The index.html and xml file are both in a spiff format folder and running!

My question is:
Can Data let's say from a sensor be loaded to the xml file?
If so, can someone guide me in the right direction?
Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE. You might find this post on our Meta site helpful: [How to ask a good question for Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange).

Comment: why xml? for Java Script JSON format is native

Comment: I spend the whole day, learning about Json! I was using samples from different websites that’s why used what they had. But now I know how to get data out of json. But I can not find any guide regards updating data every 1 second to json from Arduino.

Comment: use the Java Script setTimeout function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp to call the function which makes the AJAX request and applies the data from the response to the page